# node.js module to compare json in a configurable way

Tags: json, node.js, testing

I am working on writing a testing suite for our REST API in node.js. I am wondering if there is a module out there that does the json comparison in a configurable way.

For example : `{ "id":"456", "data":"Test_Data", "date":"2014-05-19" }`

I need to be able to tell the module, check not null for id since its autogenerated, check not null for date and check only data value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use [expect.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/expect)

```
var expect = require("expect.js");
var data = {"name":"John", "age":32};
data.toString = function(){"String"};

expect(data).not.to.be(undefined);
expect(data.name).to.be("John");
expect(data.toString).to.be.a("function");
```

Answer (score 2):

For your tests, you can use [should.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/):

```
var should = require('should');
var data = { "id":"456", "data":"Test_Data", "date":"2014-05-19" };

data.should.containEql({ id: "456" })
data.should.have.property("data");
data.should.have.property("data").with.type("string");
data.should.not.have.property("non-existing");
data.data.should.match(/^Test.*$/);
[...]
```

Happy testing!

EDIT: **you can use** instead of **use**. Also, I'm not affiliated with should.js :)